# C++0x Initializer Lists

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, initializer-list

I need some help understanding some subtleties of C++0x consolidated initializer lists.

Why does...

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    struct Foo
    {
        public:
            struct Bar
            {
                public:
                    Bar(int a, int b, int c){}

                    int ma, mb, mc;
            } mBar[2];

            Foo(int a, int b, int c)
            : mBar{{a, b, c},
                   {a+10, b+10, c+10}}
            {}
    } mFoo(1, 2, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

...result in this compiler error...

```
>g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp
main.cpp: In constructor ‘main()::Foo::Foo(int, int, int)’:
main.cpp:18: error: bad array initializer
>
```

...whereas this...

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    struct Foo
    {
        public:
            struct Bar
            {
                public:
////////////////////Bar(int a, int b, int c){}

                    int ma, mb, mc;
            } mBar[2];

            Foo(int a, int b, int c)
            : mBar{{a, b, c},
                   {a+10, b+10, c+10}}
            {}
    } mFoo(1, 2, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

...does not...

```
>g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp
>
```

...whereas if I compile the first version of the above code with a different compiler, it compiles...

```
>/opt/mv_7/arm/tools/arm-gnu/bin/arm-montavista-linux-gnueabi-g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp
>
```

?

I'd be very grateful for clarity on this. I thought I'd come to understand initializer lists because the first stab at this topic was with the cross-compiler (that compiled the first version of code with no complaints), but the above discrepancy has me puzzled now. Thank you.

Comment: What's your g++'s version?

Comment: @T.C. my native g++ version is "gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) (GCC)" and my cross-compiler version is "arm-montavista-linux-gnueabi-g++ (MontaVista Linux G++ 4.7-140920150953) 4.7.0"

Comment: Seriously, it's been *five years* since C++11 shipped. Can we please stop calling it "C++0x"?

Comment: It's unsurprising that a 2009 compiler doesn't have good C++11 support.

Comment: @NicholBolas - thank you for taking the time out of your day to post a comment that does not address the question in any meaningful way and betters neither the asker nor the community. I admire and applaud you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments you indicated that you were using gcc 4.4.7.

This is a relatively old compiler. I had no issues compiling the given code using gcc 5.3.1 in -std=c++14 mode.

If this code does not compile with the -std=c++11 flag with your compiler, it's because this older compiler hasn't yet fully implemented the C++1x standard.